# angularjs. Check if at least one checkbox is checked in a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following html:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="notification in notifications">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="{{notification.specs.length+1}}">{{notification.notification_id}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="position in notification.specs">
        <td>{{position.lot}}</td>
        <td>{{position.id}}</td>
        <td>{{position.kind}}</td>
        <td>{{position.name}}</td>
        <td>{{position.release_form}}</td>
        <td>{{position.mnn}}</td>
        <td>{{position.tn}}</td>
        <td>{{position.metric}}</td>
        <td>{{position.price}}</td>
        <td>{{position.count}}</td>
        <td>{{position.full_character}}</td>
        <td>{{position.package_count}}</td>
        <td>{{position.who_checked}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-init="position.is_checked = false" ng-model="position.is_checked"></td>
        <td style="text-align:center" ><i class="icon-folder-open"></i></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to check if at least one checkbox in the table is checked. If it's checked, I have to show a special block. If none of the checkboxes is checked, I have to hide the block.

**UPDATE**

There's no such field in model as `is_checked` when I get data from server.
Is there any way in angular to add field to model manualy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose an isChecked function, and then bind to it in your view.

Controller:

```
 $scope.isChecked = function(notifications) {
        for (var i = 0; i < notifications.length; ++i) {
        {
            var specs = notifications[i].specs;
            for (var j = 0; j < specs.length; ++j) {
                if (specs[j].is_checked)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
 };
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-show="isChecked()"> Special </div>
```

Comment: But `positions` are inside the `ng-repeat` loop. I have to use an argument in this function outside the loop.

Comment: There's no such field in my model as `is_checked` when I get data from server. Is there any way in angular to add field to model manualy?

Comment: I don't like to call functions from partials as they are called every single time $digest is in progress

Comment: This answer really worked. I don't think it's the best realisation, but still it works =) Thanks @pixelbits

Comment: yes this solution is the same as setting up a $watch on a function. But it is better than a deep $watch.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
MyApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'filterFilter',
    function ($scope, filterFilter) {
        $scope.isChecked = function(positions) {
            var checked = filterFilter(positions, {is_checked: true});
            return !!checked.length;
        };
    }
]);
```

then you can use `isChecked` function in your template.

Comment: `$scope` doesn't have a property `position`. It has a property `notification`, that has an array of `positions`. Anyway, if you filter `notification.positions` and then check the length of that, it's ok.

Comment: I updated my answer. P.S. Even though, the questioner probably wants to do that in the template directly, it's still better to show the plain code and idea...

Comment: Actually I thought I have to create a method in cotroller that returns boolean value. This thing that you wrote looks like a truth! I will try to understand this code.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should work

```
<tbody ng-repeat="notification in notifications">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="{{notification.specs.length+1}}">{{notification.notification_id}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="position in notification.specs">
        {{provisorCtrl.specs = notification.specs}}
        <td>{{position.lot}}</td>
        <td>{{position.id}}</td>
        <td>{{position.kind}}</td>
        <td>{{position.name}}</td>
        <td>{{position.release_form}}</td>
        <td>{{position.mnn}}</td>
        <td>{{position.tn}}</td>
        <td>{{position.metric}}</td>
        <td>{{position.price}}</td>
        <td>{{position.count}}</td>
        <td>{{position.full_character}}</td>
        <td>{{position.package_count}}</td>
        <td>{{position.who_checked}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-init="position.is_checked = false" ng-model="position.is_checked"></td>
        <td style="text-align:center" ><i class="icon-folder-open"></i></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<!--added-->
<div id="specialBlock" ng-if="notifications | filter:{'is_checked':true}:true">show if any checkbox</div>
```

other, maybe better way to do it would be adding ng-change on the checkboxes

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-change="boxIsSelected = position.is_checked" ng-model="position.is_checked"></td>
```

so then

```
<!--added-->
<div id="specialBlock" ng-if="boxIsSelected">show if any checkbox</div>
```

Comment: good answer. I would also change the HTML code a bit: not to use `ng-repeat` on `<tbody>` but rather `ng-repeat-start` on first `<tr>` and `ng-repeat-end` on second `<tr>`. Also the `ng-init` to `false` value is probably not required at all.

Comment: Hm... do `notifications` children have a field `is_checked`? I believe, this will not work.

Comment: Yeah, it should probably be `notification.specs`.

Comment: But the thing is that there is no notification.specs - there is `notifications[n].specs`. At least in the answer's template.

Comment: If I understood what you mean there's no field `is_checked` (this is just a client field). The structure is following `notifications[n].specs[n]`